# Initial coefficients in Thomas's algorithm

Tags: matlab, iteration, differential-equations

```
x = 0.0:0.1:1.0;
N = length(x);
h = x(2)-x(1);
a = 1/hˆ2*ones(size(x));
b = -2/hˆ2*ones(size(x));
c = 1/hˆ2*ones(size(x));
r = x.*cos(x);
a(1) = -1; b(1) = 1; r(1) = 0;
c(N) = 0; b(N) = 1; r(N) = 0;
% Forward sweep
for j = 2:N
    b(j) = b(j)-c(j)*a(j-1)/b(j-1);
    r(j) = r(j)-c(j)*r(j-1)/b(j-1);
end
% Final equation
y(N) = r(N)/b(N);
for j = (N-1):-1:1
    y(j) = r(j)/b(j)-a(j)*y(j+1)/b(j);
end
```

This is the code of Thomas's algorithm for solving y''=xcosx with initial points y'(0)=0 and y(1)=0. I don't understand why a(1)=-1 and b(1)=1. Would someone explain it to me? I get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are solving the tri-diagonal system

```
c(k)*y(k-1) + b(k)*y(k) + a(k)*y(k+1) = r(k),  k=2...N-1
```

The boundary conditions are implemented as

```
y(2)-y(1) = h*y_func'(0) = 0  ==> a(1)=1, b(1)=-1, r(1)=0 (and implicitly c(1)=0)
```

and

```
y(N)=y_func(1)=0 ==> c(N)=0, b(N)=1, r(N)=0 (and implicitly a(N)=0).
```

The algorithm computes an LU decomposition where both triangular matrices are bi-diagonal. The inversion of the L factor is applied in-place in the forward sweep, the back-substitution according to the r factor then in the reverse sweep.

Comment: What if our condition was y'(0)=1? I want to understand how to find a(1) and b(1).

Comment: Then you would set r(1)=h. It is relatively unimportant where you locate the factors h, you could as well use integer values for the other abc values, that is, multiply the inner equations with h^2.